# How to read contents in a exe file of a game created using sdl 2?

Tags: sdl-2

I was recently playing a game called Into the breach, i was fascinated by the game mechanics and wanted to learn more about the game, so i thought what better way to learn about the game by read through it's code. Fortunately the game developer has made the scripts view able directly through text editor all the script files had a .lua extension and showed how the game worked.
[Files inside the game folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OseSH.png)

But not everything was accessible for viewing like the code for the main menu.
So i tried different methods for reading the exe files, like opening the exe with Visual studio, but no dropdown would appear under the exe file, when i started to debug it the game ran perfectly well.
Also I was able extract files from the exe file using 7zip, but none of them could be read using a normal text editor.[Files found inside the exe file after extracting it using 7zip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlch8.jpg)

Is there any way to read these files through a third party program ?

Comment: No, but you could run it through a decompiler to view a version of the code, but it wouldn't be the original source. Variable names and other details would be lost.

Comment: I would imagine the lua scripts are in the `scripts/` folder.  You're not likely to be able to get anything readable out of the .exe itself.

Comment: I used ILSpy to decompile the exe but when i try to open the exe with it i get  an exception saying "PE file does not contain any managed metadata." Could it be i' might be missing some extensions or do i need to used another decompiler . Any suggestions on which decompiler can be fruitful. Because the main menu for the game is pretty well done and code for the menu is not in the script folder.

Comment: Perhaps the software wasn't written in C#?

Comment: 7z just extracted PE sections, they wouldn't get you anywhere. This is a dificult topic, it can't be explained in single post (or even single month, most likely). There are analyzers/decompilers like IDA and ghidra, but without vast experience they wouldn't get you far. Analyzing 4Mb file would be very time-consuming. If you want to learn that, start with small programs that you have source for, compile with different compiler options, load to decompiler, see how different things become, etc..